# How can I properly download a file with MsBuild Community Tasks WebDownload?

Tags: msbuild, download, msbuildcommunitytasks, msbuildextensionpack

If I do this

`[...]`

`<UsingTask AssemblyFile=".\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll"
     TaskName="MsBuild.Community.Tasks.WebDownload" />`

`<Target Name="Download">

 <WebDownload FileName="Deploy.zip" 
    FileUri="http://[...]/Deploy.zip" />

    </Target>`

the resulting file is broken and only a fraction of the size of the file. Only textfiles seem to work.

The msbuild extension pack alternative isnt working either.
(http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.5.0/html/fbcabc54-e80e-3176-dcd0-8be24fc60602.htm)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad! The **credentials** were missing.
Unfortunately there was no error message - just a downloaded broken file.
Strangely I was able to fully download a xml file.